# images do not match pil, django model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a QR Code in my Django model which creates itself whenever a new record is saved. The problem is that when testing in my dev environment everything is fine but in production I get an error on the specified line below saying: ValueError, images do not match.

```
from django.core.files import File

import qrcode
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

from datetime import date

# this is the save method of the django model class, I just left out the other methods
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    img = qrcode.make(self.account_id)
    canvas = Image.new('RGB', (400, 400), 'white')
    canvas.paste(img) # Error occurs on this line
    buffer = BytesIO()
    canvas.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    canvas.close()
    fname = f'pdf-qr-code-{self.account_id}.png'
    self.menu_qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False)

    super(PDFMenu, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't know if maybe the problem is with my configurations on my ubuntu server since that's the place where the problem takes place but maybe a new way of creating a qr code within this custom save method is necessary.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: could you post traceback

Comment: It's fine, I solved the problem by essentially creating the file independent of django and instead only storing the path to the file. It does mean that pictures with the same file name will be over written but in this use case it doesn't actually matter.